# Possibility of extracting information from an RSS feed into e.g. a beamer presentation

Tags: embedding

Is it possible to implement an RSS feed into a `beamer` presentation or are any packages planned for this functionality?

The closest I've seen is the media9 package which *does* make a call to external sources (in this case a media player), so surely it's possible to parse RSS feed information to be used in macros?

I additionally would like to stress that this is not a feature request. `:-)` I just have a specific use case where this would come in handy but would not be essential.

Comment: Interesting question -- never thought about it! Go ahead ;-)

Comment: Should the feed be accessed during compilation or during presenting?